# z-index not working for text over background video

Tags: css, z-index

I found code online that I copied to get my website's title over a looped background video.  However my efforts to add links on the left hand side of the screen are not working.  Since I want each one stacked on top of the other I assumed that flexbox would be the best way to handle but I can't even get the links to show without it.  What am I doing wrong, and what is the best way to achieve my goal?

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}

.video_main {
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video_main video {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  width: 100%px;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: -1500;
}

.content h1 {
  font-family: "jaf-domus-titling-web", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
}

.content h2 {
  font-family: "europa", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 175px;
}

.content p {
  display: block;
  font-family: "europa", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
}

h2 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video_main">
  <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload>
    <source src="http://bartonlewisfilm.com/red hook, rush hour (excerpt).mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Barton Lewis</h1>
    <h2>films about light and the urban landscape</h2>
    <p><a href="index.html" title="home">home</a></p>
    <p><a href="bartons_film_site_works.html" title="works">works</a></p>
    <p><a href="bartons_film_site_bio.html" title="bio">bio</a></p>
    <p><a href="bartons_film_site_cv.html" title="c/v">CV</a></p>
    <p><a href="bartons_film_site_contact.html" title="contact">contact</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say you want to add links to the left hand side of the screen, it sounds like you mean beside the video - however your title is about text over a background video, so do you mean you want them to show over the video down the left hand side?

Comment: yes that is correct, sorry for the confusion.  I want the links to show over the video just like the website title above and center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the z-index, its that you are not positioning the links over the video in the first place.

You have made the position for the `<p>` elements `absolute`, but you haven't told it *where* to position them. You need to use top, bottom, left and/or right to place the elements.

Instead of doing this for each individual `<p>` element, its easier to add them all to a div and then just position that one div.

**1:** Group the links into a div for easier positioning, e.g.:

```
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Barton Lewis</h1>
        <h2>films about light and the urban landscape</h2>
        <div class="videolinks">
            <p><a href="index.html" title="home">home</a></p>
            [etc...]
        </div>
    </div>
```

**2:** Remove the positioning from `.content p`, because we're going to use the div to place them

```
.content p {
    [...]
    position:absolute;   /* <- REMOVE */
}
```

**3:** Create your CSS rules to position the div, e.g.

```
.content .videolinks{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

**Working Snippet:**

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    }
.video_main {
    margin:0 auto 0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.video_main video {
     /*width: 100%;*/
    width: 100%px;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 720px;
    margin: 0 auto;  
    z-index:-1500;
    }
.content h1 {
    font-family: "jaf-domus-titling-web",sans-serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 48px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    top:75px;
}
.content h2 {
    font-family: "europa",sans-serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    top:175px;
    }
.content p {
    font-family: "europa",sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
.content .videolinks{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    z-index:100;
    }
h1  {
    width: 100%;
    }
h2 {
    width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="video_main">
  <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload>
<source src="http://bartonlewisfilm.com/red hook, rush hour (excerpt).mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Barton Lewis</h1>
        <h2>films about light and the urban landscape</h2>
        <div class="videolinks">
            <p><a href="index.html" title="home">home</a></p>
            <p><a href="bartons_film_site_works.html" title="works">works</a></p>
            <p><a href="bartons_film_site_bio.html" title="bio">bio</a></p>
            <p><a href="bartons_film_site_cv.html" title="c/v">CV</a></p>        
            <p><a href="bartons_film_site_contact.html" title="contact">contact</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Don't forget that you might need to adjust the placement of the video heading etc to make room for the links, especially on smaller screens.

Comment: Thank you so much!  One final question:  in the code I copied, there was no positioning set for the "video_main" element, but a z-index was declared.  Don't the z-index and positioning always go together?

Comment: @BartonLewis "*Don't the z-index and positioning always go together?*" - yes you are correct. The z-index on ".video_main video" isn't having any effect because of that, but its not necessary because your other elements have a higher z-index than the default anyway. FYI There are some other errors in that code too (I was only looking at fixing your links) - for example you also have "width: **100%px**" in ".video_main video". It's good that you're actually checking & questioning the code you copied and not just copying it blindly - not everything you get on the internet will be correct! :)

Comment: thanks again and for catching the other error.  Much obliged,